# SML function type

Tags: sml

I have a hard time understanding the Type of a certain SML function i need to create.

It is a helper function that should return the longest string from a list of strings.
The type should be: `(int * int -> bool) -> string list -> string`

How should i read this and how can i create a function that would match?

I started by following simple code:

```
fun helper(x,y)=x>y
```

But now i should have this method to return a string list and then a string. But i seem to be missing some points here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the signature of a curried function: `(int * int -> bool) -> string list -> string`

- `(int * int -> bool)`: this is the first argument, and it is a function that receives a tuple of two integers and returns a boolean. Looks like a predicate function.
- `string list`: this is the second argument, a list of strings
- `string`: and this is the resulting type of your function.

For instance, in the course of [Programming Languages](https://www.coursera.org/course/proglang) (which appears to be the source of the question) the function in question should look somewhat like:

`fun longest_string_helper f xs = ...`

Where

- `f` is a function value of type `(int * int -> bool)`
- `xs` is a list value of type  `string list`

And of course the function returns a `string` value.

Notice that the arguments in the function declaration are separated by spaces, and not within a tuple pattern. That evidences that this is a curried function. You can read about this in the course reading notes for section 3, under Another Closure Idiom: Currying and Partial Application (page 11).

Comment: Many thanks. It's clear now. It's almost similar like i solved the first part. Probably therefor my confusion :)